# name not defined error

Tags: python, function

In my ongoing quest to finish my tic tac toe game, I tried writing a function to check for a winner. The game looks like this: 
The board is made of a list of lists:

```
lst = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

def board():
print (lst[0:3])
print (lst[3:6])
print (lst[6:])

['1', '2', '3']
['4', '5', '6']
['7', '8', '9']

then this not so elegant function to check for a winner: 

def conclusion():
if all('o' == item for item in (lst[0],lst[1],lst[2])):
    print('Player 2 wins!')
elif all('o' == item for item in (lst[3],lst[4],lst[5])):
    print('Player 2 wins!')
elif all('o' == item for item in (lst[6],lst[7],lst[8])):
    print('Player 2 wins')
elif all('o' == item for item in (lst[0],lst[3],lst[6])):
    print('Player 2 wins')
elif all('o' == item for item in (lst[1],lst[4],lst[7])):
    print('Player 2 wins')
elif all('o' == item for item in (lst[3],lst[6],lst[9])):
    print('Player 2 wins')
elif all('o' == item for item in (lst[0],lst[4],lst[8])):
    print('Player 2 wins')
elif all('o' == item for item in (lst[2],lst[4],lst[6])): 
    print('Player 2 wins')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[0],lst[1],lst[2])):
    print('Player 1 wins!')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[3],lst[4],lst[5])):
    print('Player 1 wins!')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[6],lst[7],lst[8])):
    print('Player 1 wins')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[0],lst[3],lst[6])):
    print('Player 1 wins')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[1],lst[4],lst[7])):
    print('Player 1 wins')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[3],lst[6],lst[9])):
    print('Player 1 wins')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[0],lst[4],lst[8])):
    print('Player 1 wins')
elif all('x' == item for item in (lst[2],lst[4],lst[6])): 
    print('Player 1 wins')
else:
    pass
```

then these functions for the gameplay:

```
def move2():
conclusion()
move2=(input('Player 2: Type a number!'))
for x in lst:
    if move2 == x:
        lst[int(move2)-1] = 'o'
        board()
        move()
    elif move2.isdigit() and move2 not in lst:
        print('Not that number dipshit!')
        break
        board()
        move2()
    elif not move2.isdigit():
        print('Not that number dipshit!')
        break
        board()
        move2()


def move():
conclucion()
move1=(input('Player 1: Type a number!'))
for x in lst:
    if move1 == x:
        lst[int(move1)-1] = 'x'
        board()
        move2()
    elif move1.isdigit() and move1 not in lst:
        print('Not that number dipshit!')
        board()
        move()
        break
    elif not move1.isdigit():
        print('Not that number dipshit!')
        board()
        move()
        break
```

The problem is when I try to run it I keep getting this error:

```
<ipython-input-27-8688e8182de8> in move()
      1 def move():
----> 2     conclucion()
      3     move1=(input('Player 1: Type a number!'))
      4     for x in lst:
      5         if move1 == x:

NameError: name 'conclucion' is not defined
```

Any ideas? Suggestions for streamlining this would also be very welcome.

Comment: `def move():
conclucion()` Is it because there is a typo?  Change the last 'c' to an 's' and it should work.

Comment: Your function is called `conclusion`, not `conclucion`

Comment: Thanks that was embarrassing. But now it's saying 'list index is out of range' @Noah Christopher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spelled "conclusion" wrong, as "conclucion".